# Logical equivalence implication between Kleene and Classical logic

Tags: first-order-logic, nonclassical-logic

For any propositional assertions, $\phi$ and $\psi$, expressed using only the standard propositional logical connectives $\{\lnot,\land,\lor,\rightarrow,\iff\}$, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent in Classical logic, are they necessarily logically equivalent in Kleene logic, and vice versa? That is, is it the case that $$\phi \equiv_C \psi \iff \phi \equiv_K \psi,$$ (where C=Classical and K=Kleene)?
Logical equivalence is taken to mean sameness of truth table. I've worked out one direction of the biconditional, which is that $$\phi \equiv_K \psi \rightarrow \phi \equiv_C \psi.$$ This is because the specified set of logical connectives are classical-truth preserving in Kleene logic. So, for any two propositional assertions, $\phi$ and $\psi$, if $\phi \equiv_K \psi$, then $\phi$ and $\psi$ have the same truth table, by definition of logical equivalence. They therefore agree on all classical rows of the truth table, by the classical-truth preserving property of the set of connectives. But this set of classical rows just is the truth table for $\phi$ and $\psi$ in Classical logic, and since these rows are the same, $\phi \equiv_C \psi$. Therefore, $\phi \equiv_K \psi \rightarrow \phi \equiv_C \psi.$

But I can't figure out how to prove the other direction. I can argue that if $\phi \equiv_C \psi$, then $\phi$ and $\psi$ will agree on all classical rows of their truth tables in Kleene logic. But, I don't know what to say about the remaining rows?

Comment: This one's right, I promise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: $\phi=P$, $\psi=P\land(Q\lor\lnot Q)$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about [Kleene's three-valued logic of indeterminacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). If so , the equivalence you are trying to prove does not hold, because 
classical logic proves the law of excluded middle $\phi \lor \lnot \phi$, but Kleene's logic does not: if $U$ is the undefined truth value, $U \lor \lnot U$ is $U$ not $\top$.

[This needs to be combined with the trick in David C. Ullrich's answer as discussed below.]

Comment: It's not clear to me that that answers the question. It's true that $\phi \lor \lnot \phi$ is not a tautology, ie does not always evaluate to $T$. But there are _no_ tautologies in Kleene logic! He specified that logical equivalence means the truth tables are the same - a counterexample must involve two formulas with the same classical truth table but different Kleene truth tables...

Comment: Thanks, Rob. But, I think David's correct here. The question is not whether a given propositional assertion has the same truth table in Classical as it does in Kleene logic, but rather whether if two assertions have the same truth table in Classical, will they necessarily have the same truth table in Kleene? (You're right about the logic I'm referring to. And thanks for the link!) @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was forgetting that there is no way of writing $\top$ in Kleene's logic, so $\psi$ being provable isn't equivalent to the equivalence $\psi \equiv T$ being provable. David's trick of conjoining another propositional variable solves the problem: $P \land \psi \equiv P$ is provable iff $\psi$ is.